# Use two-way auth with certificates in Android

Tags: android, cordova, ssl

My network relies on 2 main sides:

- Node.JS Server : who works both for self-signed CA and RESTful server over HTTPS.
- Android/PhoneGAP(Cordova) App : that sends Ajax requests to the server.

Firstly I need to configure a 2-way handshake, so I created keys and certificates both for the Server and Client.
I've installed the CA-root certificate and the client certificate on Android, and i can see it from ***Settings -> Security -> Certificates -> User***.

Now, if I try to access to my server from the Browser (i.e. Safari), a pop-up shows up asking me which client certificate I want to use, than I select the installed one and everything works properly.
Instead if I try to perform the same request from the app, no pop-ups are shown, than *I can't select any certificate to my server*.

There is any way to specify the use of a certain certificate into an Android Application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution after 5 days of struggle...for both ANDROID or IOS, you need to install a Cordova plugin, to enable you application to retrieve the Client-certificates located somewhere into your WWW folder.

https://github.com/zxyang/cordova-plugin-clientcertificate

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192), or if possible all of the above.